# .htaccess in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

The main site runs WordPress with .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm going to create an CodeIgniter app in subdirectory   `site.com/online/`
If simply add CI .hta file in subfolder it wouldn't work. CI .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|img|styles|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Is it possible to combine two .htaccess files or to do something with .htaccess  in CI subfolder?
Thank you.

**UPD.**
Thank you for answers, I've tried all variants, and eventually moved project to subdomain.

Answer (score 3):

First thing, your .htaccess should be like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\s/+online/ [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

#Then add this for CI handling in the same .htaccess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^online/(.*)$ online/index.php?/$1 [L,NC]
```

Then you can remove (or rename) .htaccess in the `online` subfolder.

Comment: Thank you for answer. When I add this, brower returns to 404 if type /online/welcome/

Comment: If `online/welcome/` is a valid directory name and you want it to be handled as `online/index.php?/online` then above rule needs to be relaxed by removing condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`. Try now, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hi. Browser again redirect to Not found

Comment: +1 - this approach worked for me (basically, just add the subdirectory, in this case `online`, to the rewrite rule).

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the codeigniter .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /online
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|img|styles|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Otherwise all requests to that subfolder would be redirected down to wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride)?  According to the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) you need to allow `FileInfo` overrides for mod_rewrite.